# Based on what hidden and/or publicly available criteria are Schengen visas granted?

Tags: visa-refusals

If someone asks you that based on what criteria a loan can be granted to a bank customer you would probably talk about the customer's past and present *financial* status. You can even object against the bank manager when other irrelevant hidden criteria have been considered to reject your request, e.g. racism.

But I think we cannot object against an officer who rejects our visa. So, my question is based on what criteria Schengen visas are granted? And I mean real or 'hidden' reasons to grant/refuse visas. In addition, are those criteria available to us to read them so we can object in case that visa is refused?

PS The reason that (I joined to travel SE community and) am asking those questions because my application for home loan is rejected today because my signature is a mathematics formula and has "appeared strange and even offensive" in the bank manager's eyes !! (in Georgia). He also said "is it a code? for like a bomb?" !! My passport is Iranian and the countries are usually intend refusing to give visa, so it may be happily an excuse for them not to grant me a Schengen visa.

Comment: Welcome to Travel! I see two questions in your question. In the title you ask what the criteria for a Schengen visa are and in the body you ask if you can object. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Constantine - Thank you. I edited it. Actually now the two questions are parts of one question in the title. :)

Comment: By the way, you accepted my answer much too soon. The idea on this site is to wait until there are multiple answers and then accept the best, as guidance for others who browse the questions later.

Comment: @o.m. - sounds perfect to me esp your comment explaining signature. However I wait a while to 'accept'. By the way, thank you very much for your help. :-)

Comment: I am all in for individualism and the statement by the bank manager seems weird, but why don't you simply change your signature to something people expect, i.e. your actual name? I mean, is the trouble of having loans or visa applications rejected because of this really worth it? After all, I know many people (like myself) who have a signature which is not really readable as a name, so you could use something like this if it it is important to you and "hide" your formula in there.

Comment: @dirkk - Yes I have to change it but I am not sure if I can, I mean what would be the consequences because I am 29 years old, a little late perhaps to change signature.

Comment: @Liebe Back in 2014, I got a German D-type visa and in the consulate, I was informed that in my visa application and subsequent use in Germany, the signature should always match the signature in the passport.

Comment: Off topic: banks can legally reject a loan application for most any reason that [isn't legally prohibited](http://www.occ.treas.gov/topics/consumer-protection/fair-lending/index-fair-lending.html) (as you point out, racial or national origin are some of these criteria). Refusing a loan to someone because they act in a way you find strange is perfectly legal as long as it doesn't involve one of the protected criteria. The manager's "for like a bomb?" comment may suggest an element of discrimination though, which you could consider pursuing.

Comment: @ZachLipton - Thank you for your informative comment. (Just in parenthesis, I am in Georgia [country not state] and being against racial or national origin of somebody is not explicitly illegal as it is in Europe, US, etc. If I take somebody to a court for racism reason, people in charge might laugh at me because of 'being a sensitive baby'!)

Comment: @Liebe Ah, sorry for the confusion then. I wasn't certain which Georgia you meant, but a few aspects of your question led me to believe that you were talking about the US state. Unfortunately, much of the world does not have particularly strong or effective protections against discrimination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can appeal a refusal. The process will be described in the notice. That being said, the main criteria are:

- Did the applicant read, understand, and follow the instructions? Is the application complete and consistent? Quite a lot of people don't do that ...
- Does the applicant *appear* to be a genuine tourist or business traveller? Does the proposed itinerary make sense? Does the applicant have a realistic appreciation of the cost of living in the Schengen area?
- Does the applicant *appear* to be an illegal immigrant? A steady, well-paid job at home is a big plus. If the money for the trip is borrowed, it might look like an "investment" that will be repaid by working illegally in the Schengen area. Unexplained deposits of money are a very bad sign.
- Is the applicant known as security risk? Governments have secret databases. Some governments share some data with others. Applicants who are listed as dangerous (but not dangerous enough to draw a drone strike) would be denied entry.
- Is there a known travel history for the applicant, good or bad? Every time a tourist visa was used without overstay, that is a good sign.
- Did applicants with a *similar background* have many immigration problems in the past? That's never the **only** reason for rejection, but application from some regions are scrutinized more closely than others.

Comment: Thank you. What about figure of my signature? Is mathematical formula as a signature makes a person to be seemed not as normal as 'a genuine tourist'?

Comment: The way I understand it, a signature should be a more-or-less stylized rendering of the name. Perhaps one can't read it unaided, but when the signature is compared with the name the match should become obvious. There seem to be regional differences in this regard.